# Not in any GOPATH while using dep init

Tags: go, godeps

I'm trying to use `godep` to install my dependencies but I can't seem to get it to work. When I run GODEP init, I get the following error

> determineProjectRoot: /home/cjds/development/core/data-service not in any $GOPATH

But my GOPATH definitely contains that path. This is my whole go path

> /home/cjds/development/core/data-service

`go install` causes the following error, which may be the root of the problem:

> no buildable Go source files in /home/cjds/development/core/data-service

The folder structure however has a `src` folder, and then a `main` folder and then my whole Go project

> -/home/cjds/development/core/data-service/src/main/my-go-files.go

Comment: please read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `GOPATH` points to a root directory containing `bin`, `pkg`, and `src` subdirectories, with project source under `src`. Tools like `godep` and `go install` expect to operate on source, not on your entire `GOPATH`, so must be run on some path under `$GOPATH/src`.

Comment: Such as for `GOPATH=/Users/user/go`, you need to under `/Users/user/go/src/*`.